# ELMAH error logging in azure storage

Tags: c#, asp.net, elmah, azure-table-storage, error-logging

I'm using ELMAH error logging in my web application. I've looked through couple of topics. But there's one thing I can't understand anyway. I want ELMAH to read the logs from the DB , that I'm pointing. It's Azure Storage table, in which there are lot of error logs.

```
  <elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="yes" />
    <errorLog type="what to write here ?" connectionStringAppKey="myConnectionString" />
  </elmah>
```

I've got ErrorEntity.cs file too, and I've edited the connection string variables in it. 
But it is continuing to read the errors from my local computer.
Can You please help me with this question ?

Thanks.

Comment: After some digging, I found what to write in the "type" field, but there's another issue. VS can't bind my assembly and is giving this error.  
`Could not load file or assembly 'WindowsAzure.Elmah.Tables' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`  
I've already edited the registry record in the `HKLM\Fusion` repository, but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys. Just solved my issue. I was giving the wrong assembly path in the web config file, so it couldn't find my dll file.

Thanks.